# How to write this sql statement - inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have SQL Server with these tables

- `Statuses` -> string username, string name, string content, int id(key)
- `Likes` -> string id, string StatusId(f key), string username

I want to present every status and his likes even if it does not have any likes, in only one SQL statement; what could I do? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried.  Sample data and desired results are also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the count, use `left join` and `group by`:

```
select s.id, count(l.status_id) as numlikes
from status s left join
     likes l
     on s.id = l.status_id
group by s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present every status and his likes even if it dose not have likes,you should use left join instead of inner join.

```
Select a.*,b.username as hislike 
from Statuses a left join Likes b 
on b.StatusId=a.id
```